# How can I remove the file extension from each string in a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of strings, each string containing the name of an image file:

```
$slike=(1.jpg,253455.jpg,32.jpg,477.jpg);
```

I want new array, to look like this:

```
$slike=(1,253455,32,477);
```

How can I remove the file extension from each string in this array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're working with filenames, use PHP's built in [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function. there's no need to use regex for this.

```
<?php

# your array
$slike = array('1.jpg','253455.jpg','32.jpg','477.jpg');

# if you have PHP >= 5.3, I'd use this
$slike = array_map(function($e){
    return pathinfo($e, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
}, $slike);

# if you have PHP <= 5.2, use this
$slike = array_map('pathinfo', $slike, array_fill(
    0, count($slike), PATHINFO_FILENAME
));

# dump
print_r($slike);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 253455
    [2] => 32
    [3] => 477
)
```

Comment: Wrong. basename() only strips out extensions if an extension is provided in the suffix parameter. Could work if the OP knows the extension ahead of time, though.

Comment: My answer no longer depends on `basename`.

Comment: This is the best best answer, txanks

Comment: Got this error in log     PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in classes/prikazcokolada.inc.php on line 19

Comment: Tanja, I have a PHP <= 5.2 and PHP >= 5.3 solution posted above. Make sure to use the correct one. Which version of PHP are you running?

Comment: @salathe, thanks for adapting the answer. I would personally still use the `foreach`, but the `array_fill` technique is fine too, I suppose :)

Comment: @TanjaPakovic, PHP <= 5.2 doesn't support closures (as used in the PHP >= 5.3 answer), so make sure to use the PHP 5.2 solution provided.

Comment: @macek, it's your answer to do with as you please! I simply figured it wouldn't hurt to make the two snippets at least somewhat similar.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are your friend on this one. I'm assuming that by brackers, you mean an array.

```
$k = count($slike);
for ($i = 0; $i < $k; $i++) {
   $extpos = strrpos($slike[$i],".");
   $slike[$i] = substr($slike[$i],0,$extpos);
}
```

This is no longer regex-dependent, and benchmarks faster than pathinfo().

Comment: Great works like charm, yes bracket was array, but i hav troubles making code in editor, txanks a lot

Comment: -1 There's no reason to use regex of this problem. Not to mention, your solution is extremely rigid and expects all filenames to be completely numeric. PHP has a `pathinfo` function for this specific type of string parsing.  See my answer for details.

Comment: Not working, what if the pictures anre not numbers? If i have something like me.jpg instead of 1.jpg, than this goes wrong?

Comment: I assumed all your filenames would be of a similar format, as they were in your example. Editing for a more general case.

Answer (score 2):

Using **[`preg_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)** in **[`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)**

```
foreach ($slike as &$value) {
    $split = preg_split('/\./', $value);
    $value = $split[0]
}
```

Change the regex to `/[^.]+/` to include `a.b.jpg` as well.

Comment: In my case I did actually need it to work for file names with a double extension like that, so this was the only answer that worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
$slike = array('1.jpg','253455.jpg','32.jpg','477.jpg');

$slike = array_map(function($e){
            $e = explode('.', $e);
            return $e[0];
        }, $slike);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($slike);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Your solution wouldn't work if there was a filename like `my.new.picture.jpg`.